# How to Transfer Message to index.html after checking duplicate value?

Tags: php

Action.php

```
class dataOperation extends Database{
    public function check_Duplicate(){
       $email = $_POST["email"];
       $number = mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT Email FROM member where Email='$email'");
       if (mysqli_num_rows($number)){
         echo "Email is taken"
       } else return true;
    } 
 }

$obj = new dataOperation;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
 if( $obj->check_Duplicate()){
    if($obj->insert_record("member",$myArray)){
      header("Location: ../index.html");
      exit;
    };
 };
}
```

I am trying to print error message from action.php to index.html. How can I print "Email is taken" in index.html instead of action.php?

Comment: echo "Email is taken" <- lacks semi color ; to end the statement.

Comment: Why not just echo it? Probably, you want to write it to a session?

Comment: yes, I think about use session if there are no other way to do that.

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This basicly means that it would take less than a minute for any visitor of your website to do whatever they want with your database. That includes destroying it. Consider using [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: You need to change your `index.html` to `index.php` if you want to be able to pass data to that file using sessions/query string or similar.

Comment: @icecub thanks for your advice, I still study and not concern about security threat right now. Maybe I'll study about that later

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok I will use session, thanks

Comment: _"and not concern about security threat right now"_ - Security should _always_ be at the top of your concern. There's _never_ an excuse to knowingly write insecure code. Learn things correctly from the start and you will save yourself _a lot_ of time refactoring later. You might also want to turn your tests into a proper project at some point. Then it's pretty easy to forget to fix some of the issues and you're stuck with an insecure website.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you! Couldn't have said that better myself. OP, if Prepared Statements aren't your concern and you're not even sure if you're willing to learn it, any concept to pass data from PHP towards HTML is probably too complicated for you. It involves Ajax which is harder to understand than Prepared Statements.

Comment: Btw, Prepared Statements doesn't just help you with security. Since you're not escaping the user input at all, any input containing a single quote or ends in a back slash would break your query. With prepared statements, that's a non-issue.

Comment: do you mean using real_escape_string in form, yes i do that

Comment: That's just escaping user input. It's _not_ the same as Prepared Statements and insecure. You can't rely on it. We're not here to just point out your faults you know? If you actually want to learn, just ask. We're more than happy to point you into the right direction to learn about Prepared Statements and get you going the way you should :)

Comment: do I need to make prepared statement in all my query function?

Comment: The code you've posted does not use real_escape_string? There even are cases where real_escape_string won't help you (edge cases, but still). That's why it's always safer to use parameterized prepared statements any time you're going to use user input, or any other data that you're not in control over or can contain any invalid char.